# add values to a dataframe every nth row or corresponding to a spec. column value

Tags: r, dataframe

r-noob here with a question not to solve by himself

I hava a data frame with the length of 250

```
    head(abto, 20)
    See Transekt plant Blatt# breiteo breitez bez
 1: ABT        A     1      1  2.0182  5.3980   1
 2: ABT        A     1      1  1.9730  4.2522   1
 3: ABT        A     1      1  1.8024  3.7587   1
 4: ABT        A     1      2  2.2081  4.2880   2
 5: ABT        A     1      2  2.2858  6.1115   2
 6: ABT        A     1      2  1.8532  5.7426   2
 7: ABT        A     1      3  2.0384  4.9074   2
 8: ABT        A     1      3  2.0757  4.8801   2
 9: ABT        A     1      3  1.8034  4.6111   2
10: ABT        A     1      4  1.9567  4.8879   2
11: ABT        A     1      4  1.9080  5.0652   2
12: ABT        A     1      4  1.8346  4.8862   2
13: ABT        A     1      5  2.0282  4.5545   1
14: ABT        A     1      5  2.1356  5.7157   1
15: ABT        A     1      5  1.7594  6.1688   1
16: ABT        A     2      1  1.6457  5.2868   1
17: ABT        A     2      1  1.6942  5.0414   1
18: ABT        A     2      1  2.0544  5.6711   1
19: ABT        A     2      2  2.1342  5.2867   2
20: ABT        A     2      2  1.9107  6.2139   2
```

and a vector with the length of 84 (only a third minus 2 as the first one)

```
> head(databtzl)
  abtl.wert
1   22.7738
2   24.9137
3   24.9474
4   25.0498
5   25.0431
6   21.1024
```

basically I have a dataframe with 3 measurements of width per leaf(Blatt#) and a vector with one measurment of the length. I am trying to merge them in one, but putting the length values on every 3rd row.

I guess there are so many solutions, I was thinking of creating 2 blank cells in between every value of the vector and then merge them.

Since there are some iregularities in the data frame (twice only 2 values for the width instead of 3)I was thinking of a function/loop to assign a value of the vector everytime the value of abto$Blatt# is changing.

Sorry for the cumbersome question, I hope someone understands my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My expected output is the following table with abtl.wert as the values from the databtzl vector...

```
          See Transekt plant Blatt# breiteo breitez bez  length
     1: ABT        A     1      1  2.0182  5.3980   1  abtl.wert1
     2: ABT        A     1      1  1.9730  4.2522   1
     3: ABT        A     1      1  1.8024  3.7587   1
     4: ABT        A     1      2  2.2081  4.2880   2  abtl.wert2
     5: ABT        A     1      2  2.2858  6.1115   2
     6: ABT        A     1      2  1.8532  5.7426   2
     7: ABT        A     1      3  2.0384  4.9074   2  abtl.wert3
     8: ABT        A     1      3  2.0757  4.8801   2
     9: ABT        A     1      3  1.8034  4.6111   2
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: In the data showed, you have 20 rows, and for the second data it is 6 rows, can you check the solution I provided.  It is not very clear about how the length will match.

Comment: thanks for the effort, will try it in a sec! I edited again, the first data frame has a length of 250, the vector a length of 84. So two times there is only 2 values for the width instead of 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem, the following should work:

```
## Compute the rows in abto to add the values from databtz$abtl.wert
## Here, we look for changes in adjoining rows of the Blatt# column
## using diff. Descending in rows, the row before the change will have
## a diff != 0. We want to mark the next row as well as the first row, 
## so prepend this resulting vector with TRUE
rind <- c(TRUE, diff(abto$`Blatt#`) != 0)

## Then it is just a matter of adding a new column to abto named length
## and inserting the values from databtz1$abtl.wert only for the rows 
## that are marked (identified by which(rind==1))
result <- data.frame(abto, length=rep(NA,nrow(abto)))
result[which(rind==TRUE),"length"] <- databtz1$abtl.wert
```

This answer assumes that the number of rows in `databtz1` matches the number of rows at which `abto$Blatt#` changes.

With this input data:

```
abto <- structure(list(See = c("ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", 
"ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT", 
"ABT", "ABT", "ABT", "ABT"), Transekt = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A"), plant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), `Blatt#` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), breiteo = c(2.0182, 1.973, 1.8024, 2.2081, 2.2858, 1.8532, 
2.0384, 2.0757, 1.9567, 1.908, 1.8346, 2.0282, 2.1356, 1.7594, 
1.6457, 1.6942, 2.0544, 2.1342, 1.9107), breitez = c(5.398, 4.2522, 
3.7587, 4.288, 6.1115, 5.7426, 4.9074, 4.8801, 4.8879, 5.0652, 
4.8862, 4.5545, 5.7157, 6.1688, 5.2868, 5.0414, 5.6711, 5.2867, 
6.2139), bez = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("See", "Transekt", 
"plant", "Blatt#", "breiteo", "breitez", "bez"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))

databtz1 <- structure(list(abtl.wert = c(22.7738, 24.9137, 24.9474, 25.0498, 
25.0431, 21.1024, 28.9083)), .Names = "abtl.wert", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I get this:

```
print(result)
##       See Transekt plant Blatt. breiteo breitez bez  length
##1  ABT        A     1      1  2.0182  5.3980   1 22.7738
##2  ABT        A     1      1  1.9730  4.2522   1      NA
##3  ABT        A     1      1  1.8024  3.7587   1      NA
##4  ABT        A     1      2  2.2081  4.2880   2 24.9137
##5  ABT        A     1      2  2.2858  6.1115   2      NA
##6  ABT        A     1      2  1.8532  5.7426   2      NA
##7  ABT        A     1      3  2.0384  4.9074   2 24.9474
##8  ABT        A     1      3  2.0757  4.8801   2      NA
##9  ABT        A     1      4  1.9567  4.8879   2 25.0498
##10 ABT        A     1      4  1.9080  5.0652   2      NA
##11 ABT        A     1      4  1.8346  4.8862   2      NA
##12 ABT        A     1      5  2.0282  4.5545   1 25.0431
##13 ABT        A     1      5  2.1356  5.7157   1      NA
##14 ABT        A     1      5  1.7594  6.1688   1      NA
##15 ABT        A     2      1  1.6457  5.2868   1 21.1024
##16 ABT        A     2      1  1.6942  5.0414   1      NA
##17 ABT        A     2      1  2.0544  5.6711   1      NA
##18 ABT        A     2      2  2.1342  5.2867   2 28.9083
##19 ABT        A     2      2  1.9107  6.2139   2      NA
```

Note that I removed a row with `Blatt#` equal `3` from your original posted data to simulate your irregularities, and added a row in `databtz1$abtl.wert` so that we have equal number of changes in `Blatt#` as we do rows of `databtz1$abtl.wert`.

Comment: Wow, elegant and super efficient! forgive me, since I am a beginner this seems quite like magic. Thank you a thousand times! I think I learned a lot:) For future problems like that one, I have trouble finding useful ressources for data juggling problems. Can you recommend one? Thanks again!

Comment: @rhavan actually, a good resource is participating in StackOverflow, both asking and answering questions. You'll find new and different approaches to solving problems from the community, and then go learn about these by digging deeper into the documentation. Good luck!